# How to solve Error: NSURLConnectionInternalConnection _withConnectionDisconnectFromConnection

Tags: ios, error-handling, nsurlconnection, nsurl

in my app i am downloading a huge(200MB+) file to disk.
after the download is done i am getting this error:

```
[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection _withConnectionDisconnectFromConnection]:  
message sent to deallocated instance 0x8cb0b40
```

i try to call **info malloc-history 0x8cb0b40** but i am getting

```
Undefined info command: "malloc-history 0x8cb0b40".  Try "help info".
```

i am using *(gdb)* but still getting this info. i cant find the error here.

---

**How can i fix this issue?**

so here is my code (NSURL Methods):

```
#pragma mark - NSURL methods


- (void)loadingProgress:(NSNumber *)nProgress {
[self.progressView setProgress:[nProgress floatValue]];
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
XLog(@"");

[self.receivedData setLength:0];
XLog(@"response: %@", [response description]);


self.path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vox.zip"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:self.path contents:nil attributes:nil];
self.file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:self.path] retain];// Here file is object of NSFileHandle and its declare in .h File

[self.file seekToEndOfFile];


if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse self]]) {
    NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
    lengthOfXMLContent = [[headers objectForKey:@"Content-Length"] intValue];
    XLog(@"session: %@", [headers objectForKey:@"Set-Cookie"]);
    
    [self.prefs setValue:[headers objectForKey:@"Set-Cookie"] forKey:@"keySession"];
    
    XLog(@"headers: %@", headers);
    XLog(@"Incoming length: %i", lengthOfXMLContent);
    
}
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

//XLog(@"didReceiveData entered");

self.dataCount = self.dataCount + [data length];

if (self.receivedData) {
    
    self.paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    self.documentsDirectory = [self.paths objectAtIndex:0];
    
            
    self.responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

}

XLog(@"------------------------------------------: %d", lengthOfXMLContent);


double progress = (double)self.dataCount / (double)lengthOfXMLContent;


XLog(@"--------------: %i", self.dataCount);
XLog(@"--------------: %d", lengthOfXMLContent);
XLog(@"--------------: ");
XLog(@"--------------: %f \n", progress);


[self.file seekToEndOfFile];
[self.file writeData:data];
//XLog(@"data--------------: %i", [data length]);

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadingProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress]];
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
XLog(@"");
XLog(@"error: %@", error);


self.receivedData = nil;
self.progressView.progress = 0.00;
lengthOfXMLContent = 0;
//recievedData = NO;

UIAlertView *alertCanceled = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Verbindungsfehler" message:@"Verbindung wurde unterbrochen. \nPruefen Sie Ihre Verbindung und versuchen Sie es noch einmal." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertCanceled show];
[alertCanceled release];

viewDownload.hidden = YES;

//[self removeActivityViewer];
[connection release];
[self.file closeFile];
}


- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
XLog(@"");


[self.file closeFile];
//NSError *error = nil;
XLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", [self.receivedData length]);


[connection release];

//self.lblInfo.text = @"Datei wurde heruntergeladen.\nDatei wird entpackt, bitte Warten..";
self.progressView.hidden = YES;
self.btnDownloadVOX_DE.hidden = YES;
self.btnDownloadVOX_EN.hidden = YES;


[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;




ZipArchive *za = [[[ZipArchive alloc] init] autorelease];
[za UnzipOpenFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/vox.zip", self.documentsDirectory]];
[za UnzipFileTo:self.documentsDirectory overWrite:YES];


viewDownload.hidden = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your connectionDidFinishLoading, you release the connection while its still servicing your delegate.

I assume you have a property or ivar that retains that in your class (lets call it "myConnection"). What you should do is this in that didFinishLoading delegate:

```
connection.delegate = nil; // insure no more delegate calls
```

followed by:

```
// either this
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selectior(setMyConnection:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

// or using GCD (my preference)
dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ { myConnection = nil; } );
```

I'll bet this stops the crash. [I had similar problem with location service!]

Answer (score 2):

I would recomment you to use the AFNetworking Framework.
This Framework is much easier to handle and has many advantages of manually handling the connection. For example resumable downloads, detailled up-/dowlnoad progress, etc.

[AFNetworking on Github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. but this is one of the last steps of my current work, i dont want to add a new framework. want to solve the issue.